# How to start a daemon on server startup in spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to start a daemon mail service thread on tomcat server startup. So, I have annotated a method with @Async annotation.

I have a class which implements a ApplicationListener interface. When I call my async method from this class, it never starts asynchronously and blocks the current thread. And When I call my async method from a spring controller class, It never blocks and starts asynchronously.

Why async method executed successfully from one class and not from the other class?

What am I doing wrong and How can I execute my async method on server startup??

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I tried using the InitializingBean interface, @PostConstruct, init-method approach to call my async method, but it never executed. Then I realized, my default lazy-init is true, So I make the lazy-init to false for my InitializingBean. Now it execute my asnyc method, but it blocks the current thread and now one more issue, I am facing is that My server didn't stop gracefully, but I have to stop my server forcefully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all You don't need to implement `ApplicationListener` interface. You are working with Spring - Application context is enough.

Second you are talking about Spring `@Async`, it means that your task should be started from Application Context and Controller bean is a part of it.

You need to make sure that you have `<annotation-driven>` in your spring xml file.

You can start your task on @PostConstruct function:

```
@Component
public class SampleBeanImpl implements SampleBean {

  @Async
  void doSomething() { … }
}


@Component
public class SampleBeanInititalizer {

  @Autowired
  private final SampleBean bean;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
    bean.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Danny, Thanks, one more question, how can I execute some method on server startup, If I will not implement ApplicationListener interface.

Comment: The accepted solution won't work as stated in the following bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7560

Comment: this solution wont work as async and post contruct dos'nt work together

Answer (score 4):

Based on Spring's [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/scheduling.html), use of `@Async` has limitations during start-up of the application:

> `@Async` can not be used in conjunction with lifecycle callbacks such as
>   `@PostConstruct`. To asynchronously initialize Spring beans you currently
>   have to use a separate initializing Spring bean that invokes the
>   `@Async` annotated method on the target then.

So, in your case, maybe it'd be good to have an `InitializingBean` implementation with your target bean and then start the daemon through that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the `<annotation-driven>` tag to your application context? From the [Spring reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-namespace):

> To enable both @Scheduled and @Async annotations, simply include the 'annotation-driven' element from the task namespace in your configuration.

Note, you should also consider to configure an *executor* instance. From the [task schema definition](http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd):

> Defines a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor instance with configurable pool size, queue-capacity, keep-alive, and rejection-policy values. See Javadoc for the org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync annotation for information on code-based alternatives to this XML element.

So to create an executor that is backed up by a thread pool with 5 threads you have to do the following:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

For more configuration options, see the [@EnableAsync javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

my english is pool.
you must set the Service Class @Lazy(false).

Answer (score 0):

`@asyn` is something part of spring framework, Does your listener usage spring context? If not, I will suggest to start a new thread in your async method.

Answer (score 0):

I use `@PostConstruct` with a thread executor

```java
@PostConstruct
public void startServer() {
    final var executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(()-> {
      try {

        // make a call to a service that will not stop on it's own
        grpcServer.start().awaitTermination();

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
      }
    });
}
```

This works with [How do you use Spring Boot Actuator using JMX only on a non-web spring boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491376/how-do-you-use-spring-boot-actuator-using-jmx-only-on-a-non-web-spring-boot-app)