# How do you use Spring Boot Actuator using JMX only on a non-web spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

I am trying to create a stand alone GRPC server but with Spring Boot so I get DI and other things that are provided by Spring Boot.  What I am trying to do is implement the [health check endpoint via JMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105364/how-to-use-springboot-actuator-over-jmx/73180551#73180551) but when I run it with the following dependendices (note I commented out webflux because I don't want the webflux engine)

```
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
```

My application yaml is

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
    web-application-type: none
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: health
```

When I go to jconsole locally I don't see any of the spring boot mbeans though.

I tried to `spring.application.admin.enabled: true` and [`spring.jmx.enabled: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943892/what-is-the-exact-purpose-for-spring-jmx-enabled) with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was one of my attempts that just didn't start up correctly.  The value to enable it is `spring.jmx.enabled` so the YAML stanza would be.

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
    web-application-type: none
  jmx:
    enabled: true
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: health
```